# Recover url through ID

Tags: php, html

every day, unloading a file that contains a set of url I have to change every day in css menu that I have the page. The only thing that does not change the name assigned to the url. You assigning each a name or other ID, go to the new url css menu without changing it every day?

Today

```
file.php
    <a href='http://playlist.m3u.com/playlist1.m3u'>playlist1</a><br/>
    <a href='http://playlist.m3u.com/playlist2.m3u'>playlist2</a><br/>
    <a href='http://playlist.m3u.com/playlist3.m3u'>playlist3</a><br/>
```

Tomorrow

```
file.php

    <a href='http://playlist.m3u.com/playlist4.m3u'>playlist1</a><br/>
    <a href='http://playlist.m3u.com/playlist5.m3u'>playlist2</a><br/>
    <a href='http://playlist.m3u.com/playlist6.m3u'>playlist3</a><br/>
```

Every day changes the url but not the playlist name

```
menu_index.html
    <ul>
    <li><a href='http://playlist.m3u.com/playlist1.m3u'>playlist1</a><br/></li>
    <li><a href='http://playlist.m3u.com/playlist2.m3u'>playlist2</a></li>
    <li><a href='http://playlist.m3u.com/playlist3.m3u'>playlist3</a></a></li>
</ul>
```

On this file, I change the link every day, but I would find a way to not edit it every day if possible.
The index is a menu in css menu dropdown, I would like to avoid having the classic white page with hyperlinks.

Answer (score 0):

if i'm right understand you:

```
<?php $array = array('playlist1','playlist2','playlist3');?>

<ul><?php

 foreach($array as $val){

  ?><li><a href='http://playlist.m3u.com/<?=$val?>.m3u'>playlist1</a><br/></li><?php

 }

?></ul>
```

Comment: It's something like this would be fine but it does not work, I tried to declare but variable  `<?php   
$Val_get = $_GET['val'];
?> `But when I click on the menu playlist1, he tells me not found

Comment: can you show me this page/web-site? i'll try to help. Cuz i don't rly understand what are you talking about now, and why u need $_GET?

Comment: Please try the updated code, use `<li><a href='http://playlist.m3u.com/?=<?php echo"$val"; ?>.m3u'><?php echo"$val"; ?></a><br/></li><?php } ?></ul>`